# Совместимость библиотеки Winsock между языками

Tags: vb6, visual-studio, c#

Скажите, вот у меня в Vb 6.0 был компонент Winsock - для создания чатов, онлайн игр и др. А вот где этот компонент в Visual Studio?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под Visual Studio? Среду разработки или вы перешли на другой язык, С++, к примеру?

Comment: Я перехожу на C#, но компоненты в Visual Studio одинаковые на всех ЯП(я так думаю)

Comment: Правильно в ответах сказано, библиотека winsock системная, она всегда есть. А если Вас интересует библиотека winsock2, то она подключается отдельно. Иначе не вижу смысла вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

**Winsock** Это библиотека для работы с сетью на уровне сокетов и она в самой операционной системе, и даже если у Вас нет ее в среде разработки то к ней всегда можно обратится с помощью WinApi.

Лежит сама DLL в папке Windows/system32

Comment: Да но вот как её найти среди списка компонентов в Visual Studio?

Comment: Не факт что она у Вас есть среди установленных компоненнтов.

Comment: Ну как-то ведь люди делают чаты, онлайн проекты на VS, значит она есть, просто называется как-то по другому. Вот как называется, очень интересно.

Comment: Ну а кто Вам мешает использовать WinApi ?
Да и компонентов для работы с сетью достаточное количество.
В конце концов Вам ни кто не запрещает экспортировать функции из самой DLL

Comment: Всем спасибо. Уже разобрался.